# Что лучше, единый домен для всех стран или же региональные домены? инфа в описании

Tags: веб-программирование

У меня стоит вопрос на счет создания доменного имени. Хотел бы посоветоваться у вас.

Стоит задача зарегать домен, но тут то есть дилема. Или же создать один интернациональный домен по типу .com .org и т.д. или же зарегать отдельные домены для разных стран типа news.ru, news.ua, news.kz, news.kg и т.д.

От этого зависит функционал сайт самого. Ведь когда люди будут заходить они должны будут выбирать страну если это точка ком. Если например точка ру то автоматически считается что человек в России и контент будет аналогичен.

Comment: Все зависит от масштаба проекта. Зачем на маленький проект кучу доменов? Если на каждый будет заходить по 1000 человек. Проще тогда на .com поставить скрипт, который по IP определяет страну пользователя и соответственно язык. И сделать допустим ru.news.com, us.news.com

Comment: С технической точки зрения для грамотно организованного бэкенда сайта не будет разницы между news.com/ru/ и news.ru. Но вообще я в последнее время как-то наблюдаю тенденцию к отказу от кучи доменов (из последнего — lastfm.ru → last.fm), возможно это связано с большой вознёй по SSL-сертификатам

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Делать домены в национальных доменных зонах, на мой взгляд, есть смысл только в следующих случаях:

1. Когда у вас есть бренд.
2. Когда ваш бренд настолько известен, что домены с его именем могут быть заняты кибер-сквоттерами, и это, в свою очередь, может нанести те или иные потери бренду.
3. Когда ваш бренд настолько известен, что вы ожидаете достаточно серьезной доли трафика от пользователей, которые первым делом, ища вас в интернете, будут сразу набирать что-то вроде `adidas.ru`.
4. Когда предполагается, что и функционал сайтов в разных доменных зонах предполагается разный, и команда, управляющая им, будет отдельной командой (например, разные редакции вашего СМИ). Отсюда также будут выливаться и различия в бренде и в его тонкостях для разных стран.

Проще говоря, создание доменов в национальных зонах - это скорее вопрос не техники, а защиты бренда. Во всех остальных случаях проще и удобнее создать единый домен, и на нем уже организовывать зоны для различных стран - это никак не будет противоречить ни с логикой поисковиков и продвижения в них, ни с логикой рекламы, ни с логикой функционирования самого сайта.